# OR operation on two memory locations pointed by pointers

Tags: c

I would like to perform a bitwise OR operation on two memory locations pointed by pointers and store it an char array.

I am struck on performing OR operation on two memory locations and later assign them to char array.

```
void perform_or_operations ( struct storage *a, struct storage *b )
{
     char array[0x1000]; // size of array is bigger than struct storage

     // Perform OR operation
     array = a | b ???

}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Do you really want to perform it on the locations (`a` and `b`) and not on the objects located there (`*a` and `*b`)? (Neither operation makes much sense, though,  unless "or" is a sensible operation for `storage` objects.)

Comment: Yes , I would like to perform it on data stored in the memory locations. Deferencing them to (char)is my first thought, but wondering if there could be easier way of doing an OR operation as the size of data locations are equal

Comment: @ChuckCottrill I think you mean `*(char *)a` and `*(char *)b`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to operate on the representations of the two structures.  You really ought to use `unsigned char` instead of `char` for that, but it's quite possible either way.  A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to a character type, and the resulting pointer may be used to access the representation of the pointed-to object.  However, you absolutely need to *dereference* such pointers -- your code attempts to operate on the pointers themselves.

Moreover, there is no whole-array assignment in C.  If I understand correctly what you want to do then you'll need to perform the bitwise or on each byte of the representation independently.

Finally, you may find it to your advantage to zero out the array, so that those bytes that don't correspond the the representation of a `struct storage` have consistent values.

**Example:**

```
void perform_or_operations ( struct storage *a, struct storage *b ) {
    unsigned char array[0x1000] = { 0 };
    unsigned char *a_bytes = (unsigned char *) a;
    unsigned char *b_bytes = (unsigned char *) b;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*a); i++) {
        array[i] = a_bytes[i] | b_bytes[i];
    }
}
```

Substitute `char` for `unsigned char` (everywhere) if you really need to work with that type.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an OR of the bytes that make up the structs that `a` and  `b` point to, you would do the following:

```
char *ap = (char *)a;
char *bp = (char *)b;
size_t i;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(struct storage); i++) {
    array[i]  = ap[i] | bp[i];
}
```

The first two lines create character pointers to each struct that can be used to access the bytes of each.  Then you OR the corresponding bytes;

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.
You want to cast a and b to (char*), and using temporary variables ap, bp saves cluttering the code with casts. then you dereference (*) the ap and bp pointers (or use/interpret them as array).

```
void perform_or_operations ( struct storage *a, struct storage *b )
{
    char array[0x1000]; // size of array is bigger than struct storage
    size_t size = sizeof(struct storage);
    if( size > 0x1000 ) size = 0x1000; //guardrail
    unsigned char *ap, *bp;
    ap = (unsigned char*)a;
    bp = (unsigned char*)b;

    for( size_t ndx=0; ndx<size; ndx++ ) {
        //perform OR operation
        array[ndx] = *ap++ | *bp++;
        //or this way - which do you prefer?
        array[ndx] = ap[ndx] | bp[ndx];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that 1000 != 0x1000.